# Save commits without push

Tags: git, github

What happens to commits without push when the disk will formatted? I have some commits, but my Winchester was broke. Can I restore my commits in another device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local commit information are stored in the `.git` directory in your project. So if that gets deleted or if you format the disk the commit data is gone. You have to apply the same disk recovery methods/tools to recover that.